# Tmux Status Bar default window names

Tags: tmux

On one of my clients' servers, I've been using the `tmux` status bar to monitor long-running processes, both through the automatic window-name changes and by setting window names through ANSI control codes in scripts. It's incredibly useful when you have to run a dozen processes at a time and see which ones are finished.

They recently moved the server to a new provider (Amazon AWS, I believe), and suddenly `tmux` is crippled. There's no automatic name-changes on the `tmux` status bar, <strike>and it won't respond to the scripts' name-changes</strike> (it *does* respond to some script changes, I'll have to work out why it isn't doing all of them).

I've tried various configuration changes, but nothing seems to make a difference -- the "name" is always `X:login@hostname:workingdir` (where X is the window index).

Am I doing something wrong, or is it a limitation of the server? In either case, is there some way to fix it?

Here's my current `.tmux.conf` file:

```
set -g xterm-keys on
#bind-key C-b last-window
set -sg escape-time 20
setw -g mode-keys vi

# Reload the config file on demand.
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf

set -g set-titles on
setw -g allow-rename on
#setw -g monitor-activity on
setw -g automatic-rename on
setw -g window-status-current-format "#I:#W#F"
setw -g window-status-format "#I:#W#F"
```

Old system: CentOS 6.10
Old `tmux` version: 1.6
New system: CentOS 7
New `tmux` version: 1.8

Comment: What OS are you running in AWS? Ubuntu? AWS Linux? What version of tmux are you running? What version did you used to run? It sounds to me like you're using an older version of tmux which maybe doesn't support renaming windows? But I'm guessing.

Comment: @Rumbles: added that info. Both the OS and `tmux` are newer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be the value of `PROMPT_COMMAND`, set in `/etc/bashrc` on the new server, overwriting anything I put as the window title every time the prompt was shown. :-(

Comment: Same problem here. But I assume $PROMPT_COMMAND cannot be overwritten. Did you find another fix?

Comment: @RobRomijnders, it has been several years, but I vaguely recall that that problem turned out to be caused by `byobu`. It was reading `/etc/bashrc` and overwriting my `.tmux.conf` commands. I don't recall exactly how I fixed it, maybe modifying `byobu`'s own file.